# Layout constraints for dynamically created buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to create a view with dynamically created buttons. I am finding it difficult to set the constraints for inner objects other than first one that's created. Where is the issue?

[image: User Choices]

Create & Add buttons to view

```
-(void) createButton:(NSString *) btnText isButton:(BOOL) type  phraseWidth:(NSInteger) width view:(UIView *) currentView {
if (!type) {  // if it's a button then create label & button at same place else only create button
             // align left to prev button, align baseline
    if (prevX == 5) { // button left aligned to rowView, right align none
        UIButton *btnView = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        btnView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        [currentView addSubview:btnView];
       NSDictionary *dictScrollConst = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(btnView);
        NSString *hConstraint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:|-%f-[btnView]|",prevX];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:hConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:dictScrollConst]];
        NSString *vConstraint = @"V:|[btnView]|";
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:dictScrollConst]];
        prevObject = btnView;

    }
    else { // align new button to previous button
        UIButton *btnView = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        btnView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
        [currentView addSubview:btnView];
        NSDictionary *dictScrollConst = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(prevObject,btnView);
        NSString *hConstraint = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"H:[prevObject]-%d-[btnView]",kHorizontalSidePadding];
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:hConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:dictScrollConst]];
        NSString *vConstraint = @"V:|[btnView]|";
        [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:dictScrollConst]];

     }

   }
}
```

Doesn't allow constraint to be added with respect to previous button created. Throws up exception:

> Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint

Comment: You're asking too much at once. Break it down to _one_ problem and ask about that, please. No one wants to fix 50 lines of code for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping on that, I have removed the block that's not part of problem. I hope it helps others understand the problem now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's still way too much code for me to work out what's going on, but this much is obvious:

```
    NSString *vConstraint = @"V:|[btnView]|";
    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:vConstraint options:0 metrics:nil views:dictScrollConst]];
    [currentView addSubview:btnView];
```

Those lines are in the wrong order. You cannot add a constraint involving a view (here, `btnView`) at a time when that view is not in the view hierarchy. (That is exactly what the error message is telling you, though granted it phrases it in rather coy terminology.)

So, add the subview. *Then* add the constraint that affects it.

---

What I suggest you do is what I always do: start *very simple* and work your way up to the full extent of the actual problem. So, I suggest as an exercise that you begin with the second row of your layout, and see if you can do just this simple exercise: given the array of titles `@[@"Yellow", @"Purple", @"Blue", @"Red"]`, can you use it to generate four buttons horizontally?

Here's *my* code for doing that. Notice how clear and simple it is - ruthlessly logical, spare, and plain. We can always add tweaks later, but this is the kind of simplicity you need to try to maintain and build upon, so that you don't confuse yourself:

```
NSArray* titles = @[@"Yellow", @"Purple", @"Blue", @"Red"];
UIView* previousButton = nil;
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    UIButton* b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [b setTitle:titles[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:b];
    [self.view addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(100)-[b]" 
      options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"b":b}]];
    if (i == 0) {
        [self.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(50)-[b]" 
          options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"b":b}]];
    } else {
        [self.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[p]-(20)-[b]" 
          options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"b":b, @"p":previousButton}]];
    }
    previousButton = b;
}
```

Given this, we see at once one of the things wrong with your code: there is no evidence that you are setting the previous button (your `prevObject`) on any except the first pass, when of course you need to do it on *every* pass.

Once we have code that works, we can start to modify it to approach what you are wishing to do. For example, it is now easy to change the hard-coded spacing to use variables like yours instead:

```
NSArray* titles = @[@"Yellow", @"Purple", @"Blue", @"Red"];
UIView* previousButton = nil;
NSInteger initialX = 5; // *
NSInteger horizSpace = 10; // *
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    UIButton* b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [b setTitle:titles[i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:b];
    [self.view addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(100)-[b]" 
       options:0 metrics:nil views:@{@"b":b}]];
    if (i == 0) {
        [self.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(initialX)-[b]" 
          options:0 metrics:@{@"initialX":@(initialX)} views:@{@"b":b}]];
    } else {
        [self.view addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[p]-(horizSpace)-[b]" 
          options:0 metrics:@{@"horizSpace":@(horizSpace)} views:@{@"b":b, @"p":previousButton}]];
    }
    previousButton = b;
```

And so forth. The point is: This is how I "grow my code", starting always with the simple and evolving, making sure it works at every iteration, until I reach the thing I'm really trying to do. Go ye and do likewise!

Comment: I have removed the clutter. The changes that you mentioned still throw up same error

Comment: May I ask what you think this is supposed to do: `"H:|-%f-[btnView]|"` What the heck is `%f` in that? - Oh, I see. Look, this may have nothing to do with it, but that is not how you insert numbers into a visual format. Use the metrics dictionary; that is what it is for.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still confused. What's `prevX` and `prevObject`? And how do we know that things are happening in the order you expect?

Comment: Perhaps it would help to hone the problem still further. Here is an array of four button titles: `@[@"Yellow", @"Purple", @"Blue", @"Red"]`. Can you write code that lays out four buttons with those titles horizontally?

Comment: prevX is calculated value I use to check if I should horizontally align to superview, I update it once the first button is created so that I can apply constraints between 2 buttons. prevObject is the button relative to which the new button should match constraints.

by creating static buttons I can put the constraints , but not if it's in a loop and constraint has to be calculated dynamically

Comment: Well, I think you are confusing the heck out of yourself. :) You have certainly confused the heck out of me - and I lay out interface in code all the time. So, seriously, do what I suggested: just try to write the code that turns the array of strings `@[@"Yellow", @"Purple", @"Blue", @"Red"]` into four buttons laid out horizontally. If you can do that, we can proceed to worry about the previous row.

Comment: Brilliant, and thanks for your suggestions. Autolayout trips me off, especially when its through code. But your explanation is exhaustive.